# Debugging WordPress

Tags: sql, performance, debug

Looking for advice on debugging sql queries. I find that plugins and themes are causing heavy queries and slowing performance. Any easy ways for doing this? Tools? Shortcuts?
Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: You can try [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin.

Comment: [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is an elaborate one.

Comment: One of the site members has a free plugin available on wordpress.org called [Debug Objects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-objects/) which I use on my development site

Answer (score 1):

The basic technique of logging queries is that if `SAVEQUERIES` constant is defined to be `true` (it's not by default for performance reasons) then `$wpdb->queries` will keep the log of queries performed.

There isn't anything on top of this that WordPress natively does. There are plenty of plugins around which work either by interpreting this data, or implementing additional data collection. Latter can get pretty intricate to implement and only done in more elaborate debug plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Other than Debug Bar and Query Monitor, what other plugins are available?

Comment: Any other debugging tip?